# Load and predict new data sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, joblib

I trained a Logistic model, cross-validated and saved it to file using joblib module. Now I want to load this model and predict new data with it. 
Is this the correct way to do this? Especially the standardization. Should I use scaler.fit() on my new data too? In the tutorials I followed, scaler.fit was only used on the training set, so I'm a bit lost here.

Here is my code:

```
#Loading the saved model with joblib
model = joblib.load('model.pkl')

# New data to predict
pr = pd.read_csv('set_to_predict.csv')
pred_cols = list(pr.columns.values)[:-1]

# Standardize new data
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_pred = scaler.fit(pr[pred_cols]).transform(pr[pred_cols])

pred = pd.Series(model.predict(X_pred))
print pred
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, it's incorrect. All the data preparation steps should be fit using train data. Otherwise, you risk applying the wrong transformations, because means and variances that `StandardScaler` estimates do probably differ between train and test data.

The easiest way to train, save, load and apply all the steps simultaneously is to use Pipelines:

**At training**:

```
# prepare the pipeline
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.externals import joblib

pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogisticRegression)
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
joblib.dump(pipe, 'model.pkl')
```

**At prediction**:

```
#Loading the saved model with joblib
pipe = joblib.load('model.pkl')

# New data to predict
pr = pd.read_csv('set_to_predict.csv')
pred_cols = list(pr.columns.values)[:-1]

# apply the whole pipeline to data
pred = pd.Series(pipe.predict(pr[pred_cols]))
print pred
```