# how to do predict test data when no Y value is present

Tags: analytics, data-science

I have a data set from kaggle .The data set is already split-ed into train and test .The train data set has all the columns including 'X' and 'Y' but in test data their is no 'Y' only 'X' is exist.How can i predict for 'Y'(which is not present in test data). I have already trained the train data set.Now i want predict for 'Y' in test

train has x1,x2,x3,Y
test has x1,x2,x3

Comment: Follow this tutorial : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416982/load-and-predict-new-data-sklearn

Comment: follow this tutorial : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416982/load-and-predict-new-data-sklearn